# Animate using a pixmap or image sequence in Python with QT4

Tags: python, qt4

I have a small Python script that makes a transparent window for displaying a graphic on screen and I'd like to animate that graphic, but am entirely unsure how or where to even start. Here's what I do have at least:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, Qt, QtCore

class Transparent(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("test1.gif")
                pixmap2 = QtGui.QPixmap("test2.gif")
        width = pixmap.width()
        height = pixmap.height()

        self.setWindowTitle("Status")
            self.resize(width, height)

            self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)


        def animateEvent():
                    imgnumber = 0
                    try:
                        if imgnumber == 1:
                            self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("test1.gif"))
                            self.setMask(pixmap.mask())
                            imgnumber = 0
                        else:
                            self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("test2.gif"))
                            self.setMask(pixmap2.mask())
                            imgnumber = 1
                    finally:
                        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, animateEvent)

                animateEvent()


        def paintEvent(self,event):
        self.setAttribute(Qt.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    x = Transparent()
    x.show()
    app.exec_()
```

This feels like it has the right ingredients, but the pixmap doesn't update.

I tried QMovie, but then the area of the window that is supposed to be transparent is filled with black instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a simple correction of an oversight in the end.

`imgnumber` needed to be outside of the def as `self.imgnumber` and needed to be named `self.imgnumber` each time it was changed.

Answer (score 0):

First, just make sure your animated gif really does have a proper transparent background. The following code works for me, using [this fire image as a source](https://web.archive.org/web/20170327025533/http://i1104.photobucket.com/albums/h329/zorq1/Realistic-fire-animated-transparent-gif.gif):

```
class Transparent(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        filename = "test.gif"
        
        size = QtGui.QImage(filename).size()

        self.setWindowTitle("Status")

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setMargin(0)

        self.movie = QtGui.QMovie(filename)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setMovie(self.movie)

        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.resize(size)

        self.movie.start()
```

This will create a completely transparent and frameless window, with the animated gif playing in a QMovie. There is no black being drawn behind the image. It should fully see through to what ever is underneath.

It is not so far off from your original code. You shouldn't need to set the mask, or do a paint event.

Comment: For me, this has the same problem as mentioned in the original post: unlike with QPixmap, QMovie fills the window with a black background.

Comment: Using the same code I have and same image I linked? What opersting system and qt version?

Comment: Yes, even with the same image. I'm using ArchLinux with PyQT4.9.5-3

Comment: I guess I cant reproduce it unless I try it out on a linux box. Works fine in osx.

Answer (score 0):

check out this code from [www.daniweb.com](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/116827/pyqt-and-gif) and see if you can modify it to your needs:

```
import sys 
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import * 

class MoviePlayer(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self, gif, parent=None): 
        super(MoviePlayer, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("QMovie to show animated gif")

        self.movie_screen = QLabel()
        self.movie_screen.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)        
        self.movie_screen.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter) 

        btn_start = QPushButton("Start Animation")
        btn_start.clicked.connect(self.start) 

        btn_stop = QPushButton("Stop Animation")
        btn_stop.clicked.connect(self.stop) 

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout() 
        main_layout.addWidget(self.movie_screen)
        main_layout.addWidget(btn_start) 
        main_layout.addWidget(btn_stop)
        self.setLayout(main_layout) 

        self.movie = QMovie(gif, QByteArray(), self) 
        self.movie.setCacheMode(QMovie.CacheAll) 
        self.movie.setSpeed(100) 
        self.movie_screen.setMovie(self.movie) 


    def start(self):
        """
        Start animation
        """
        self.movie.start()

    def stop(self):
        """
        Stop the animation
        """
        self.movie.stop()


app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
player = MoviePlayer("/path/to/image.gif") 
player.show() 
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```